# How do I find the related function when y isn't in the original functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

I have this problem here: 
[image: [problem]
It's in the section on parabolas 
It seems to me like x = 1 and -1
But I have no idea what I'm supposed to do for y.  Also, everything else in this section has parabolas for answers, so I think I might be on the wrong track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$2x^2-5=-3$$
Figure out this $c$
$$2x^2-c = 0$$

Draw $y=2x^2-c$, the $x$-intercepts correspond to the solution of the original problem.